# directive "link" doesn't apply as I want it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, x-editable

Ok I got a page with some input managed with angular x-editable.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Morgorth/xezbs8gn/)

The following directive:

```
treeView.directive('selectWhenEditing',function(){
    var linkFunction = function(scope,startingelem,attr)
    {
        console.log(startingelem[0]);
        console.log (startingelem[0].querySelector('.editable'));
        angular.element(startingelem[0].querySelector('.editable')).on('click',function(){   
            //console.log(startingelem[0]);
            angular.element(startingelem[0].querySelector('.editable-input').select());            
        });

    };
    return{
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link:linkFunction
    };}
);
```

Is supposed to make that when I click on an editable element, the text is selected.

Here is the code of the page:

```
<tr ng-repeat="properties in elementToEdit" ng-if="fieldsSettings[$index][1]==1">
            <td>
                    {{ fieldsSettings[$index][0] }}
            </td>
            <td data-select-when-editing>                                    
                <span editable-text="properties.prop" onbeforesave="" ng-if="fieldsSettings[$index][2]== 'text'">
                            {{ properties.prop || 'empty' }}               
                </span>
                <span editable-select="properties.prop" onbeforesave="" ng-if="fieldsSettings[$index][2]== 'select'" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in fieldsSettings[$index][3]">
                            {{ selectElement(properties.prop,$index) || 'empty' }}               
                </span>
            </td>                                
    </tr>
```

and that's the relevant compiled HTML:

```
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-if="fieldsSettings[$index][1]==1" ng-repeat="properties in elementToEdit">
    <td class="ng-binding"> Name </td>
    <td data-select-when-editing="">
        <span class="ng-scope ng-binding editable editable-click" ng-if="fieldsSettings[$index][2]== 'text'" onbeforesave="" editable-text="properties.prop"> Food </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The directive is firing as I wish it (eg: the number of times of expect it).
The first console.log logs me the calling TD element as expected. But the second one is null, as it never finds an element ".editable" inside this TD, so obviously the text is never selected (event "on" isn't applied).

I've done the exact same thing in another page/module and it works well. I'm comparing the codes but cannot find a difference.

You guys see something ?

Comment: suggest taking advantage of `jQlite` which uses jQuery methods syntax and using `startingelem.find('.editable')`. No need to create a new `angular.element` since `startingelem` is already one

Comment: ok thanks ... now it does find an element but still when I apply the "on click" event on it... I'll try more tomorrow morning, it's late :)

Comment: ok I'm actually doing this and it finds an element but if I do startingelem.find('.editable').text() console is "empty string" which is not the case. I'm not sure it's selecting the right thing...

Comment: create a demo that replicates your problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Morgorth/xezbs8gn/ here is the fiddle, a bit simplified but gets the same results in the console

Comment: @charlietfl That's actually the whole problem, you can't use jqLite's find() to select anything else than the tags (see my answer). Not sure why they made it so limited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element), jqLite's `find()` function is "Limited to lookups by tag name", which means you can't use it to select elements by classes - so you need to use `querySelector` instead. Note that you also need `startingelem[0]` instead of just `startingelem` when using it.

I had to use `angular.element` to get the jqLite object for `on()` binding (you can use plainJS there as shown below), so it looks a bit ugly:

```
angular.element(startingelem[0].querySelector(".editable")).on('click',function(){
    startingelem[0].querySelector('.editable-input').select();
});
```

Here is the fully working version: http://jsfiddle.net/ar7znuz5/

---

Plain JS version using `addEventListener`:

```
startingelem[0].querySelector(".editable").addEventListener('click',function(){
    startingelem[0].querySelector('.editable-input').select();            
});
```

And the fully working version: http://jsfiddle.net/ar7znuz5/1/

---

The last version, with selects and a newer original code: http://jsfiddle.net/ar7znuz5/7/

Comment: thanks for that answer. If you look at my code on stack and not on the fiddle, you'll see that it's exactly what I wrote originally. The issue remains then (apparently the fiddle does not reproduce the error...), although as you can see by comparing my exact code and the fiddle,  the difference in the compiled HTML is quite small, the JS is the same...

Comment: Have a look at this one:

Comment: Have a look at this one:http://jsfiddle.net/Morgorth/ar7znuz5/2/ I repeated the code written above and it seems that putting two "span" with a ng-if condition breaks the link function, this is probably due to timing somehow.. I'm not sure..

Comment: You had syntax errors there, see the fixed link: http://jsfiddle.net/ar7znuz5/3/ Seems fine now, right?

Comment: sorry it seems my shared fiddle wasn't saved:http://jsfiddle.net/Morgorth/ar7znuz5/4/ I added a span and an ng-if condition , so in HTML only one span per td is compiled.

Comment: Yeah, seems like the ng-ifs actually cause a delay, the span is not available at the execution time. You can add watchers to fix this, but the simplest solution would be to attach the click listener on the root element (td itself), see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ar7znuz5/5/

Comment: that is indeed very clever :) thank you very much. although it generates a js error when there is no input... I'm gonna have a look at watchers.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes you need to go against the wind, you're welcome. :) I'm pretty sure the only errors I've seen were coming from the select input, which has no `select()` method, of course. If you think I'm wrong, just let me know and I'll revisit the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67903/discussion-between-eagle1-and-shomz).